# Fragment livedata observer called only once with default value

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I am just not able to figure out what is wrong in this code and why the observer is not called when the value is updated. I am using Fragement with livedata and here is the complete code. When app starts fragment gets it value from default data which in this case is 100. But after the value is updated using `queueChannelId(channelId)` method the observer is not called. I put a print statement and I can see method is executed in main thread. Please help

Fragment:

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = 
ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SomeViewModel::class.java)

    viewModel.getChannelId().observe(this, Observer {
        // Only called with default value of mutablelivedata

    })
}
```

I can assure that onDestroyView and onDestroy have not been called anytime.

ViewModel:

```
fun getChannelId() : MutableLiveData<Int> {
    return repository.getChannelId()
    }
```

Repository:

```
var channelIdObservable = MutableLiveData(100)

fun queueChannelId(channelId: Int) {
    channelIdObservable.value = channelId
}
fun getChannelId() : MutableLiveData<Int> = channelIdObservable
```

Comment: Fix this line : `var channelIdObservable = MutableLiveData(100)` with this one : `var channelIdObservable = MutableLiveData<Int>()`

Comment: @DHAVALASODARIYA that can't be the issue.

Comment: if you are calling `queueChannelId` from some other Thread try `channelIdObservable.postValue (channelId)` anyway try this . i cant see any other issue here.

Comment: My blind guess is that you are either reassigning `channelIdObservable` or calling `queueChannelId` on a different repository instance.

Comment: @SanlokLee You are right, after some debugging, I found that the repository instances are different. I thought I had the instance being singleton but apparently it is created new for each viewmodel. So I guess that is the bug. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you are calling `queueChannelId` from some other Thread try

```
channelIdObservable.postValue (channelId)
```

P.S: I cant see any other issue here.Share your code of how are u calling `queueChannelId`.

Comment: Thanks Anmol, I found the issue and updated the comment section above. The issue was I had different instances of the repository object. I think I will have to make the repo object singleton.